# Running Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following snippet of code and when I access the local host I get an error: Cannot GET /

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("function has started");
});

express().listen(3001);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You have to hook your router into your Express app object with `app.use(router)`.  That's why all Express apps create an `app` object and hold onto it so that they can register routes in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})

app.listen(3001)
```

This should be fine

Comment: There is no need for a router since that is already built into the app. This answer is the simplest and cleanest!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the router, you need to use the `use` method [example](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.use) (`app.use('/', router)`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express()

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send("function has started");
});

app.use('/', router)

app.listen(3001);
```